# How do I draw a circle with Style Stroke and fading edge in android

Tags: android, fadein, geometry, ondraw, radial-gradients

I am trying to draw a circle with Style:STROKE. Following is the image, that I am trying to achieve. The centre white part should be transparent.

I tried the following code

```
RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient((getRight() - getLeft())/ 2,(getBottom() - getTop()) / 2, (getRight() - getLeft()) / 2, new int[] { getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent), mCirclePaint.getColor()}, new float[] { 0.1f, 0.9f}, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
mCirclePaint.setShader(gradient);
canvas.drawCircle((getRight() - getLeft()) / 2, (getBottom() - getTop()) / 2,
            ((getRight() - getLeft()) / 2) - 10, mCirclePaint);
```

and paint is defined as

```
 mCirclePaint = new Paint();
 mCirclePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
 mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mCirclePaint.setARGB(255, colorEnums[5].getColorR(), colorEnums[5].getColorG(), colorEnums[5].getColorB());
```

[image: inner_fading_circle]

How do I do this... Whats wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RadialGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html#RadialGradient(float,%20float,%20float,%20int[],%20float[],%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)). In the constructor `public RadialGradient (float x, float y, float radius, int[] colors, float[] positions, Shader.TileMode tile)` you can see the float[] positions piece is when the colors start and stop. Just set the gradient as you want, apply it to a `Paint` and then `canvas.drawCircle()`. Should do the trick.